What is the length scale of correlated errors observed on the 72-qubit google chip used in the quantum memory experiment
I would like to have a rough idea of the length-scale over which the correlated errors of unknown origin have been observed in the Google quantum memory experiment.
One possible way to deduce this would be to know the size of the 72-qubit chip they used for this, or the inter-qubit distance.
I did not find the information in the paper: is their a place where it can be found?

Are you asking about the size of each qubit, or the distance between neighboring qubits? Or the actual size of the chip itself, less the packaging?

@MarkSpinelli The distance between neighboring qubits would be good but I could also use the size of the quantum chip itself. Thanks!

Out of curiosity what does the size of the chip or the inter-qubit distance suggest about the nature of the correlated errors?

I like Aaronson's suggestion that Gil Kalai is in a neighboring room pulling a lever every hour (Kalai hasn't refuted it!)

@MarkSpinelli they observed correlated errors spread over multiple qubits. If the qubits are separated of $x \ cm$ it means that the noise correlations spread on at least $x \ cm$ in the superconductor.

Probably less than 60 square centimeters or so?  A fully packaged device fits well into the palm of one's hand.
For example I'm not sure if it's the specific 72-qubit device used in the memory test having the correlated errors, but here's an image of one of a chip from one of Google-AI's recent videos:

Also, from the same video here is another clip of some die on what appears to be a 50mm-diameter wafer:

The video states that they make their chips in a cleanroom in Santa Barbara, California.
